# CSRF Token mismatch on prod only with Laravel / Inertia

Tags: php, laravel, axios, csrf, inertiajs

The Inertia docs says

> ..., be sure to omit the csrf-token meta tag from your project, as this will prevent the CSRF token from refreshing properly.

Doing this works well in my local environment, but it's giving me a token mismatch error in the production environment.

I inspected the request being sent and I noticed some differences between the two environments in the request headers :

In the local env :

- Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN={{SET_CORRECTLY_HERE}}
- X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
- X-Xsrf-Token: {{SET_CORRECTLY_HERE}}

In the prod env :

- Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN={{SET_CORRECTLY_HERE}}
- X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
- X-Xsrf-Token is **NOT** set

I went to `resources/js/bootstrap.ts` to inspect how the headers are being attached and this is what I found :

```
import axios from 'axios';

window.axios = axios;
const token = document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]')?.getAttribute('content') ?? null;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token;
```

The meta tag of course shouldn't exist in both envs (after being deleted from app.blade.php), yet somehow it's being attached correctly to the request in local but not in prod.

To confirm that it's not this code that's attaching it in local, I commented it out and it's still working correctly.

How do I fix this in prod ?